# JQuery on change .closest context?

Tags: jquery, this, onchange, closest

I have a form where I change a fieldset on change of the select fields.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="ajx" id="ajx_1">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Inhalt</legend>
        <select id="u_article" ...>
        ...
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

With the following JQuery it works for all modern browsers:

```
$(".ajx").on("change", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    console.log($this)

    // ... additional code for understanding what I want to do:
    var $form = $('form');
    var method = $form.attr("method").toUpperCase();
    var $this = $(this).closest('.ajx');
    var $ser = $(".ajx select").serialize();
    var $ser2 = $(".ajx input").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        data: $ser,
        type: method,
        success: function(res) {
            var $fnd = '#' + $this.attr('id') + ' fieldset';
            $this.html($(res).find($fnd));
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) { 
            alert('Unknown error - status: ' + status); 
        }
    });
});
```

In the console of Firefox I can see that there is Object and context is `Object[div#ajx_1.ajx]`.

Now the above **does not work for older Firefox** like FF7 or FF3.6 because I need to set the `change` directly to the correct fields.

I tried it with this JQuery code:

```
$(".ajx select").on("change", function() {
    var $this = $(this).closest('.ajx');
    console.log($this)
    // ...
});
```

Now the Object is correct but when I open the Object in the console I get the something different in context: `select#u_article`.

It seems like it does pick my `select` instead of the `div` as element here.

Why is this and how can I change this?

Comment: Does `u_article` also have an `.ajx` class?

Comment: no because the whole `fieldset` is replaced and not only the `select`.

Comment: I don't really see how the `context` property is an issue here. It contains `select#u_article` because that's the selector you passed in your change handler, which is correct. You shouldn't rely on the `context` property anyway, it was deprecated in 1.10, and may be removed without notice - http://api.jquery.com/context/

Comment: I see, then there must be some other property that is causing the issue... I added the full JQuery code for you to better understand what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After i understood the question, i think i have a solution:
reattach the events onsuccess of the ajax:

```
$this.find("select").on("change", theChangeFunction);
```

Here is a [jsFiddle with the complete code](http://jsfiddle.net/eyg2n5ea/5/)

Comment: Your code `if($this.is("div.ajx")) {` is true for both of my cases above, so the issue on older Firefox (tested on FF3.6 and FF7) remains...

Comment: is your question why it's a select in the context when you use $(".ajx select") ?

Comment: My problem is, the AJAX is replacing the `fieldset` and then the code doesn't work when you change the `select` field a second time. You sadly can't test this via JSFiddle because AJAX is not allowed.
I try to find out, if I can explain better and update my question. Sorry it's a bit complicated for me :)